# Select equal rows diagonally in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns containing three rows. These rows could come in different orders.
I want to create a new Boolean column detecting which rows have equal values diagonally.

```
import pandas as pd

data1={'Column_1':['BR','BR','AC'],'Column_2':['AC','LF','LF']}
data2={'Column_1':['BR','AC','BR'],'Column_2':['AC','LF','LF']}
data3={'Column_1':['AC','BR','BR'],'Column_2':['LF','LF','AC']}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3=pd.DataFrame(data3)
```

so as shown in the picture I want to add a new Boolean column `Diagonal`  to the data frame that it can detect when `column_1` is equal to `column_2` diagonally. So for example column_1[2].eq(column_2[0]) as shown in the pictures.
The code should work no matter what the order of the rows is and if possible even when I have more than 3 rows.

[image]

Comment: @ScottBoston Diagonal is True if a row from column_1 contains a value which is diagonally equal to another row from column_2. In the first example case first and third rows,  diagonal would be True. Second row, diagonal would be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IICU you want a new column `Diagonal` that is `True` if the row value of `Column_1` is somewhere in `Column_2` or vice versa, but not in the same row:

```
df['Diagonal'] = df.Column_1.isin(df.Column_2) | df.Column_2.isin(df.Column_1) & (df.Column_1 != df.Column_2)
```

Result:

```
  Column_1 Column_2  Diagonal
0       BR       AC      True
1       BR       LF     False
2       AC       LF      True
```

---

Update for additional question in comment:

If you want to do the same for individual groups instead of the whole dataframe, you can `apply` the operation groupwise. Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Column_1':['BR','BR','AC','BR','AC','AD'],'Column_2':['AC','LF','LF','AD','LF','LF'],'Column_3':['x','x','x','y','y','y']})
df['Diagonal'] = df.groupby('Column_3').apply(
    lambda x: x.Column_1.isin(x.Column_2) | x.Column_2.isin(x.Column_1) & (x.Column_1 != x.Column_2)).values
```

Result (note that the last but one row is `False` despite `AC` being in `Column_1` because it's in another group on `Column_3`):

```
  Column_1 Column_2 Column_3  Diagonal
0       BR       AC        x      True
1       BR       LF        x     False
2       AC       LF        x      True
3       BR       AD        y      True
4       AC       LF        y     False
5       AD       LF        y      True
```

Comment: Hi @Stef, thank you for your answer, this is what I'm looking for. One more question: if I want to do that separately for two different groups in the data frame (grouped by column_3) ... can I replace df by df.groupby(column_3) in the above code?

Comment: @thephoenix not exactly, please see my updated answer for this case.